# Nest.JS LoggerService interface Implementation to use Winston logger require instantiation of implementation in consumer class

Tags: node.js, logging, winston

I use Nest.js and implemented LoggerService to customize logger. In implementation, it uses Winston logger and it work fine.

```
import { LoggerService } from '@nestjs/common';
import * as winston from 'winston';
import { config } from '../config';
import * as path from 'path';
export class AppLogger implements LoggerService {
  private logger: winston.Logger;
  constructor(label?: string) {
    this.initializeLogger(label);
  }
  initializeLogger(label?: string) {
    this.logger = winston.createLogger({
      level: config.logger.level,
      format: winston.format.json(),
      transports: [
        new winston.transports.File({ dirname: path.join(__dirname, './../log/debug/'), filename: 'debug.log', level: 'debug' }),
        new winston.transports.File({ dirname: path.join(__dirname, './../log/error/'), filename: 'error.log', level: 'error' }),
        new winston.transports.File({ dirname: path.join(__dirname, './../log/info/'), filename: 'info.log', level: 'info' })
      ],
    });
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
      this.logger.add(
        new winston.transports.Console({
          format: winston.format.simple(),
        }),
      );
    }
  }
  error(message: string, trace: string) {
    this.logger.log("error", "MyLogger error - " + message);
    this.logger.error(message, trace);
  }

  warn(message: string) {
    this.logger.log("warn", "MyLogger error - " + message);
    //this.logger.warn('warn', message);
  }

  log(message: string) {
    this.logger.log("info", "MyLogger error - " + message);
    // this.logger.log('info', message);
  }
```

Every controller, I have to import the the implemented logger and instantiate the same at the class level to call the respective log method as shown below.

```
import { Controller, Get } from '@nestjs/common';
import { config } from './../../config';
import { AppLogger } from '../app.logger'
@Controller()
export class HealthcheckController {
  private start: number;
  private logger: AppLogger = new AppLogger();
  constructor() {
    this.start = Date.now();
  }

  @Get('healthcheck')
  async get() {
    const now = Date.now();

    this.logger.error("This is from Healthcheck log","");
    return {
      status: 'pass',
      version: config.version,
      details: {
        uptime: `${Number((now - this.start) / 1000).toFixed(0)}`,
      },
    };
  }
}
```

In the Main.ts

```
 this.app = await NestFactory.create<NestFastifyApplication>(
      AppModule,
      new FastifyAdapter({ logger: new AppLogger('Nest') }),
    );
```

Please advise, how to avoid instantiating the logger on all controller.

What is the best approach.

```
  private logger: AppLogger = new AppLogger();
```

Answer (score 2):

use Dependency injection to inject the service to your controller using the constructor.

```
export class HealthcheckController {
...
public constructor(private readonly appLogger: AppLogger) {}
```

and dont forget to use @Injectable() decorator in your service

```
@Injectable()
export class AppLogger implements LoggerService {
```

[Dependency injection fundamentals](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/custom-providers#di-fundamentals)

Comment: Tis is not exactly link-only, but still could use some explanation.